# In-call status bar for app

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I would like to know if there is a way to make your app show a status bar when the app is performing a specific function. Sort of like Shazam does when Auto Shazam is on, but this might be because the microphone and not something in Shazam's app code but I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically achieve this. Preferably in Swift but Obj-C also works.

[image: images.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't done directly by the app, this is done by the OS when the app is using one of a few features in the background

The bar is **red** when an app is using the **microphone** in the background.
The bar is **blue** when an app is accessing **location** in the background.
The bar is also **blue** when a device is connected to the **Personal Hotspot**.
The bar is **green** when the **telephone** (including WhatsApp) is being used.

There may be more colours for other scenarios, but these are the ones I've come across.

*I don't know of a way to add this bar on demand.*

Comment: How would apps like Messenger or WhatsApp signal that a user is in a "call"?

Comment: The bar also goes green for WhatsApp. I checked by calling my colleague.

Comment: Oh I see so if my app signals that it's in a "call" I can get a green bar that shows during the function in my app that resembles a "call"?